# How I can check when my RV item is swiped?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture

I have found [this](https://github.com/MarkOSullivan94/SwipeRevealLayoutExample) interesting solution. I added class which will represent item at RV and then I noticed that I have a small problem. At my list I have to insert two actions: swipe RV item and long click item. When I swipe item and see swipelayout but don't remove finger from RV item my adapter thinks that I'm making long click and show dialogue for long click listener. So, how I can prevent listening long click when my item is swiped. Right now I have [this](https://github.com/MarkOSullivan94/SwipeRevealLayoutExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/markosullivan/swiperevealactionbuttons/SwipeRevealLayout.java) class which helps me in swiping. Hope you will help me :)

Comment: As it is quite a bit of code it is hard to see at first glance where the logic is that you are referring to. Please use the code blocks and only use the link as an overall reference. In general, if you detect a long click you could check that you did not do a swipe (or moved your position more than a certain threshold).

Comment: @Bram, which code I have to add, because I tried to solve this problem for a long time, but I didn't manage. I posted here only link to class which help with swiping, so which info I have to add for getting help from you?